# Notebook-specific settings in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I would like to specify settings in VS Code that only apply when working with a (Jupyter) notebook.

I know language-specific settings are possible with this syntax, e.g. for Python:

```json
"[python]": {
    "editor.some.setting": "something"
}
```

However, there seems to be no option to select `python-notebook` or something similar as a language. **Is there any workaround for this?**

(Specifically, I would like to disable the final newline for [autopep8](https://pypi.org/project/autopep8/) formatting when inside a Jupiter notebook by setting `"python.formatting.autopep8Args": ["--ignore", "W292"]`)